# Cell Reference Offset In Final Analysis From Single Line Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I've tried solving this problem on my own. However, I have yet to find an example or reference that fits to my particular situation.

---

I have the following Dataset:

[image: Sheet Electronics]

However, since I cannot post more than two links, I cannot show the other sheets -- but they are equally similar.

They are single line items. (Also note, that my numbers are constantly changing in this case because I am using "=RANDBETWEEN(0,1000)". Do not focus on the numbers.

---

My Problem arises when I try to do my store analysis on my final page.

This is my problem:

[image: Analysis Sheet -- Problem]

STORE 1, JAN 16 : Electronics Cell "E4" is "Electronics!E5"

STORE 2, JAN 16 : Electronics Cell "E10" is "Electronics!**E11**"

When it should be "Electronics!**E6**"

---

This is just an example, my actual data has thousands of lines of data, otherwise I would just brute force this.

Any idea on what to do?

Thanks,
Calrabian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to do a reference search with a `VLOOKUP` or `MATCH` function, instead of counting on locations alone.

For example, assuming your data is in `Electronics!$C$1:$F$10`, you can use an **array formula** in `E4` and copy it to `E11`:

```
=INDEX(Electronics!$C$2:$F$10,MATCH($C4,Electronics!$A$2:$A$10,0),MATCH(E$3,Electronics!$C$1:$F$1,0))
```

*Use <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Enter</kbd> to enter the formula as an **array formula**, and then copy to **E11**.

Explanation:

- The main formula structure is `INDEX(<data area>, <match Store row>, <match Date column>)`.
- The `INDEX` function returns data in an array/reference according to a provided row and column indexes.
- The `MATCH` functions find the index, horizontally or vertically.
- The first `MATCH($C4,Electronics!$A$2:$A$10,0)` finds the Store row in the stores column A. C4 is the store name to find. You can play with this reference to suit your needs.
- The second `MATCH(E$3,Electronics!$C$1:$F$1,0)` finds the Date column in the dates row 1.

You can make it more flexible and complex, but this is the general idea.

Comment: I used this as well. This results in precisely what I was looking for. I'm saving your answer in a Word document for later use.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

First off I must say your dates really bug me.  Using yy-mmm for some and mmm-yy for others just throws me for a loop.

For an actual answer.  Since you are not moving 1 cell at a time you will need to do some math to have a consistent formula all the way down.

First thing you need is to get a formula that returns the right row.
row 4 returns row 5
row 10 returns row 6
row 16 returns row 7 (assumption)

Use the function

`=int((row()-4)/6)+4`

Then insert it into an index function and you have your solution

`=index(Electronics!E:E,int((row()-4)/6)+4)`

Comment: This is perfect.

Sorry about the dates, it was just an example. Thank you for your help. This was EXACTLY the answer I was looking for.